# Having issue in showing the contents of table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm working in `HTML` with `CSS` and I'm not much familiar with `CSS`. The issue I'm facing is that the width between cells (9 & 10) and cells (11 & 12) is omitted.
I have attached my `HTML` code with `CSS`.

[image]

[My desired output is as shown. Color doesn't matters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDBcE.png)

The space between the cells can be maintained, if I set `padding-left` value equal to the value of `width`. But I don't want to use this because in other cells it is maintained without setting `padding-left` value.

```css
.Csstestbodybg {
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.div3 {
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 70.75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.f1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 0.8333em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.c1 {
  color: #000000;
}

div.Csstestflex-container1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

div.Scenario12_Table1_div5 {
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 0.00%;
  margin-bottom: 0.00%;
  margin-left: 16.67%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  border: 0px;
  width: 16.67%;
}

div.Scenario12_Table1_div6 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 0.00%;
  margin-bottom: 0.00%;
  margin-left: 0.00%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  border: 0px;
  width: 16.67%;
}

div.Scenario12_Table2_div7 {
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 0.00%;
  margin-bottom: 0.00%;
  margin-left: 100.00%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 50.00%;
}

div.Scenario12_Table2_div8 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 0.00%;
  margin-bottom: 0.00%;
  margin-left: 0.00%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  width: 50.00%;
}

div.Scenario12_Table2_div9 {
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 0.00%;
  margin-bottom: 0.00%;
  margin-left: 100.00%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 50.00%;
}

div.Scenario12_Table2_div10 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 0.00%;
  margin-bottom: 0.00%;
  margin-left: 0.00%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  width: 50.00%;
}
```

```html
<body class="cssbody cssbodybg">
  <div class="Page24852 Csstestdiv div3" name="Section">
    <div>Table Style:<br>&#160;</br>
    </div>
    <div class="Csstestflex-container1">
      <div class="Scenario12_Table1_div5">7</div>
      <div class="Scenario12_Table1_div6">8
        <div class="Csstestflex-container1">
          <div class="Scenario12_Table2_div7">9</div>
          <div class="Scenario12_Table2_div8">10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Csstestflex-container1">
          <div class="Scenario12_Table2_div9">11</div>
          <div class="Scenario12_Table2_div10">12</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: whats desired output?

Comment: As my HTML and CSS is generated using my C++ application, so the format and tags used in CSS will be same as above. If I need to update or add any new tag I can do that, but format will be same.

Comment: I mean how should  all the boxes look can you update your post with an image. Should they look like the answer below I understand not to change the html but what about how they look??

Answer (score 0):

Your post didn't much say about desired output but mentioned flex. A solution using flex

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div name="Section">
    <div>Table Style:<br>&#160;</br>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-row">
      <div class="flex green">7</div>
      <div class="flex flex-col yellow">8</div>
      <div class="flex flex-row">
        <div class="flex flex-col green">
          <div class="flex">9</div>
          <div class="flex">11</div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col yellow">
          <div class="flex">10</div>
          <div class="flex">12</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```